# Action of finite group on a set of subgroups is transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite non-trivial group and $X$ be a non-empty set of all subgroups of $G$ which satisfy the following:

(1) Any two elements of $X$ are either disjoint (i.e., intersection is trivial) or identical.

(2) For all $H\in X$, we have $N_G(H)=H$.

(3) $G$ acts on $X$  by conjugation.

Show that all elements of $X$ are conjugates.

**My attempt:** We need to show that the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive. If $G$ is Abelian, then all its subgroups are normal and so $X=\{G\}$, in which case we're done. So assume that $G$ is not Abelian. Then $|G|\geq 6$. If $|G|=6$, then $G=S_3$. In this case, $X$ becomes the set of all Sylow-2 subgroups of $G$ and so we're done by Sylow's theorem.

By induction, assume that the result holds for all groups with order less that $|G|$ and fix $H\in X$. Consider the action of $H$ on $X$. Since $|H|<|G|$, this action is transitive by induction hypothesis. In particular, all elements of $X$ are conjugates.

> Is my "proof" correct? If yes, are there any alternate ways to prove the result? If not, how do I proceed?

**Edit:** As @lulu pointed out, my solution is incorrect. Other attempts I have made are that I have shown that ${\rm Stab}_G(H)=H$ for all $H\in X$ and so by orbit-stabilizer theorem, $1<|{\rm Orb}(H)|=[G:H]$ for all $H\in X$.

> I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Not following,  the elements of $X$ won't generally be subgroups of $H$ (indeed, if $X$ contains another element $H_1\neq H$ then $H_1\cap H=\{e\}$ by construction)...so how can you apply the induction hypothesis?

Comment: @lulu You're right. I have edited my question to include more attempts.

Answer (score 3):

In the assumptions of the problem, Burnside's (counting) lemma yields:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\#\text{ of orbits} &= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{H\in X}|H| \\
&\le \frac{1}{|G|}(|G|-1+|X|) \\
&=1+\frac{|X|-1}{|G|} \\
&<2
\end{alignat}
and hence $\#\text{ of orbits}=1$.

Comment: Shouldn't the sum run over $g\in G$?

Comment: Yes, @BrauerSuzuki, but isn't, for a general $G$-action on a set $X$, $\sum_{g∈G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|=\sum_{x∈X}\left|\operatorname{Stab}(x)\right|$?

Comment: Yes, that is a nice argument.

Comment: Out of curiosity, this same equation can be used to prove that, if $p\nmid q-1$, then $C_p$ acts trivially, only, on $C_q$, *without* any prior knowledge of the structure of $\operatorname{Aut}(C_q)$.

Comment: This also follows from Sylow's theorem ($C_p$ must be normal in a group of order $pq$).

Answer (score 2):

If $H \in X$, then the $G$-conjugates of $H$ form a TI set, so there are $|G:H|$ such conjugates and the union of their non-identity elements has size $|G|(|H|-1)/|H| = |G|- |G:H|$, and hence there are only $|G:H|-1$ non-identity elements that do not lie in a conjugate of $H$.

So there are not enough elements left for another subgroup $H_2 \in X$ that is not conjugate to $H$, and so $X$ consists of the $G$-conjugates of $H$.

Equivalently, a finite group has at most one faithful action that is a  Frobenius group.

Comment: What is a TI set?

Comment: Trivial intersection.

Comment: I see that the number of conjugates of $H$ is $[G:N_G(H)]=[G:H]$. So the number of non-identity conjugates of $H$ is $|G|-|G:H|$. But how do you conclude that there are only $|G:H|-1$ non-identity elements that do not lie in a conjugate of $H$?

Comment: You seem to be confused. The number of non-identity elements of $G$ that lie in a conjugate of $H$ (not the number of non-identity conjugates of $H$) is $|G|-|G:H|$, so that leaves $|G:H|$ other  elements, and one of those is the identity.

Comment: Why is $|G:H|$ not sufficient to form another subgroup which is not conjugate to $H$?

Comment: That's three questions! Please stop asking questions and think about it.

Comment: I did. Suppose that $H_2\in X$ is not conjugate to $H$, then $|H_2|\leq |G:H|$ and number of non-identity elements of $G$ that lie in a conjugate of $H_2$ is $|G|-|G:H_2|$. Thus, $G$ has at least, $2|G| - |G:H_2|-|G:H|$ elements. I can't see how to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: It has that many non-identity elements, but that number is at least $|G|$.

Comment: You mean to say that $2|G|-|G:H_2|-|G:H|\geq |G|$. In other words, $\frac{1}{|H_2|}+\frac{1}{|H|}\leq 1$? Why?

Comment: I am sorry but I have answered enough questions.

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate Derek's argument: If $H_2\in X$ is not conjugate to $H$, then by the same argument, there are $|G|-|G:H_2|$ non-trivial elements in the conjugates of $H_2$. Since they do not lie in conjugates of $H$, we obtain
$$|G:H_2|\le|G:H_2|(|H_2|-1)=|G|-|G:H_2|\le|G:H|-1.$$
Interchanging $H$ and $H_2$ yields a contradiction.